# The variable is inaccessible

Tags: c++

After I declared this class:

```
class Person
{
 private:
  int age;
 public:
  void setAge(int age);
  int getAge();
}
```

in the .h file and I implement the set and get method:

```
void Person::setAge(int age)
{
  this->age = age;
}
int Person::getAge()
{
  return age;
}
```

in the .cpp file

I'm trying to access the age variable from main.cpp file after a booked the object from another class 'Employee' that inherit from 'Person' class

```
Employee emp;
cin >> emp.age;
```

but I get this error:

> member Person::age is inaccessible

Comment: That's the point of private members. On a side note, it might as well be public like this. Does it really make sense to let the user set the age to whatever they want (including a negative number) at any time? Age cannot do that.

Comment: Might as well make it `unsigned char` instead of `int`...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Okay, but that wouldn't buy you anything.

Comment: @NiklasB.: It buys you the comfort of knowing that it can't be negative or too large. Fewer invalid states == fewer potential bugs in the longer run.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Using unsigned types has produced more bugs for me than they have prevented, but that might just be me

Comment: @NiklasB.: It's just a rule of thumb, it's not always true. The idea is, if you have fewer edge cases to worry about (e.g. negative numbers) then it's less likely you'll forget to handle all of them properly. I used to resist using unsigned numbers for anything but now I hate using signed numbers for anything that doesn't absolutely require them.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You can also put it the other way round: unsigned numbers are in some sense more complex than the signed counter-parts, for example because the invariant `a + b < c <=> a < c - b` doesn't hold in the integer range where you usually work (around `0`), which is especially confusing in cases like `for (a = n; a >= 0, --a)`. It all comes down to a matter of opinion, I guess :)

Comment: @NiklasB.: It's exactly the same problem you encounter when you use iterators, no? `for (BidIt i = end; i != begin; --i)` fails in exactly the same way, yet you don't see people using this example as a recommendation to shun iterators. If you're used to avoiding this then unsigned numbers should be no different -- you get used to this pretty quickly if you use iterators.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Your example doesn't really make sense, since `end` is not a valid iterator and `begin` is one, so you'd have to dereference `i - 1` inside the loop. You have the option to use `rbegin()` and `rend()`, though and avoid any confusion. As I said, it's a matter of taste and opinion :)

Comment: @NiklasB.: lol, it just depends on what you're doing inside the loop. E.g. if you're doing `some_backward_decoding(i, end())` then there's no need to dereference `i - 1`, this is really the most natural way to do it. But point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an accessor for *reading* the current `age`, and a mutator for *writing* the current age.  To use your class, you will need to read into a temporary variable and then use your *mutator* to change it.

```
Employee emp;

int employee_age; // temporary variable to read in age...
cin >> employee_age;

// using the mutator to set age
emp.setAge(employee_age);
```

Comment: still it giving me this error on the '>>' operator : no operator matches these operands !

Comment: Did you include `<iostream>`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the getters and setters for accessing age. Since age is a private variable, and private variables are not inherited, that's why you can't access the age variable from employee class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the getter and setter methods instead of trying to access the field directly.

```
emp.getAge() //will give you the current age.  
emp.setAge(25) //will set the age to 25.
```

Your example would be:

```
cin >> emp.getAge()
```